# Export data to Excel file from SQL Server database

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a program that can export data from sql server database to 
excel file and the file name must be auto generated and auto incremented.

I query data from server using date time picker as below:

```
 `command.CommandText = ("Select * from ComponentCheckerSystem where 
 Last_Update between  @FromDate AND @ToDate;")
 command.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = 
 DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
    command.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = 
  DateTimePicker2.Value.Dat`

    'set final path

    Dim fileName As String = "\Summary of Operator Scan Wrong Items" 
    + ".xls"    'just set the file Name 
    Dim finalPath = f.SelectedPath + fileName
   txtPath.Text = finalPath
  oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
```

Please help me to make a function to auto generate file name. 
thank you.

Comment: I want...I want...I want.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Sorry I mean, How to ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a place in Settings for your data:
1.Project Menu > Properties (all the way at the bottom)
2. Choose the Settings tab (on the left)
3. File out the boxes Name: LastFile, Type: Integer, Scope: User Value: will be set for you to 0
Actually, you could store your LastFile variable value in a text file or a database but I chose App.config for convenience.
You already know how to set your directory and the following code will get you a new file name.

```
Private Function GetNewFileName() As String
    Dim FileSuffix As Integer = My.Settings.LastFile
    FileSuffix += 1
    Dim NewFileName As String = String.Format("\Summary of Operator Scan Wrong Items{0}.xls", FileSuffix)
    My.Settings.LastFile = FileSuffix
    Return NewFileName
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim file As String = GetNewFileName()
        Debug.Print(file)
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @Mary thanks for the reply but i get error $ character is not valid ?? please help.

Comment: No error for me. I ran the code and it behaved as expected. What versions are you using? I have Visual Studio Community Edition on Windows 10 and targeting .Net 4.7.1 You can change that bit of code to String.Format("data{0}", FileSuffix)  The Interpolated string in the code was not available until later versions of VB but String.Format has been around forever.

Comment: I'm using vb 2010 on window 7.

Comment: I do like this,                                                                                       Private Function GetNewFileName() As String
        Dim FileSuffix As Integer = My.Settings.LastFile
        FileSuffix += 1
        String.Format("data{0}", FileSuffix)
        My.Settings.LastFile = FileSuffix
        Return NewFileName

    End Function                                                                                                          still getting error in Return NewFileNae not declared.

Comment: Yes Please, thanks in advance your such an angel :) i really appreciate your help.

Comment: where should i insert your code in my code ? what should i delete in my code ? please help me.

Comment: After configuring your settings, add the Function anywhere in the class. Call the Function where you need a new file name. You will have to add your extension to the return value. The Button click is just to test the function and would not be added to your code.

Comment: I already configure my settings and no error, please check my code above. in 'set final path, do i need to remove that ? because i declare a fixed file name to that . i try to call the function in that area but didn't work, i also try to delete all of that and call your function still not work. please help me.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect your code. Replace  'Set final path
            Dim fileName As String = "\Summary of Operator Scan Wrong Items" 
    + ".xls"  with Dim fileName As String = GetNewFileName()

Comment: thanks a million ... now it works .God Bless you @Mary  one more thing how can i call a message box if there is no data to be exported in excel ? example if the date i choose has no data . i want a message box .show that no data. please help me. thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the question ban. I do not know what the rules are. Microsoft has a VB forumn.
After dataAdapter.Fill(datatableMain) Add 

If datatableMain.Rows.Count < 1 Then 
 MessageBox.Show("No Data:) 
 Exit Sub 
End If

Comment: thanks it works i analyze your code and change it to <2 because my code auto generate the header . thanks a lot.